# WSDL with Delphi XE8 array initialize

Tags: arrays, soap, wsdl, delphi-xe8

I have this WSDL imported with Delphi XE8, I can not initialize array.

```
type
elencoDettagliPrescrInviiErogatoType = array of 
dettaglioPrescrizioneInvioErogatoType;
----------------------------------
dettaglioPrescrizioneInvioErogatoType = class(TRemotable)
private
FcodProdPrest: stringType;
----------------------------------

InvioErogatoRichiesta = class(TRemotable)
….
Published
property ElencoDettagliPrescrInviiErogato: elencoDettagliPrescrInviiErogatoType  read FElencoDettagliPrescrInviiErogato write FElencoDettagliPrescrInviiErogato;
--------------------------------


function  invioErogato(const InvioErogatoRichiesta: InvioErogatoRichiesta): 
InvioErogatoRicevuta; stdcall
```

My call

```
procedure Tform1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
richiestaInvio : InvioErogatoRichiesta;
ricevutaInvio  : InvioErogatoRicevuta;
begin
richiestaInvio :=  InvioErogatoRichiesta.Create;
// how to initialize arrays?
setlength(richiestaInvio.ElencoDettagliPrescrInviiErogato,1);
// Error memory not read 
richiestaInvio.ElencoDettagliPrescrInviiErogato[0].codProdPrest := 'Codice_test';
...
end;
```

I tried various ways to inizzialize  ElencoDettagliPrescrInviiErogato[0] Without success.

Comment: setlength(richiestaInvio.ElencoDettagliPrescrInviiErogato,1);
E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter.    
How can I assign this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: declare a variable 
    
    `var
    richiestaInvio : InvioErogatoRichiesta;
    ricevutaInvio  : InvioErogatoRicevuta; 
    dettagliImp  : elencoDettagliPrescrInviiErogatoType;
     // initializes  array
    begin
    richiestaInvio :=  InvioErogatoRichiesta.Create;
    ricevutaInvio  :=  InvioErogatoRicevuta.Create;
    //my problem was this. Now solved!
     setlength(dettagliImp,1);
     // create dipendence
    dettagliImp[0] := dettaglioPrescrizioneInvioErogatoType.create();
     //popolate field array
    dettagliImp[0].codProdPrest    :='cod test';
    //ecc.
    // end 
     richiestaInvio.ElencoDettagliPrescrInviiErogato := dettagliImp;
    ...`